# Does the family of fat Cantor sets contain a measurable rectangle?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fractals

Let $S \subset (0, \frac{1}{3}) \times [0, 1]$, be the set such that for each $0 < t < \frac{1}{3}$, $S \cap (\{ t \} \times [0, 1])$ is the standard [Smith-Volterra Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) of parameter $t$.

**Question:** Do there exist measurable subsets $E$ of $(0, \frac{1}{3})$ and $F$ of $[0, 1]$, both of nonzero Lebesgue measure such that $E \times F \subset S$, perhaps up to a set of $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $0$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  The intuition here is that sets that are missing a lot of "diagonal strips" cannot contain large product sets (even if the strips are very narrow).

For technical reasons it is convenient to work with the left half $S_l = S \cap (0,\frac{1}{3}) \times [0,1/2]$ of $S$, so that all the missing intervals in the Smith-Volterra Cantor set move leftwards with $t$ rather than rightwards.  By symmetry it suffices to show that $S_l$ does not contain $E \times F$ up to null sets for some positive measure $E, F$.

By construction, $S_l$ consists of the trapezoid $T := \{ (t, x): 0 < t < 1/3; 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1-t}{2} \}$ with the sets $I_{k, \epsilon_2, \dots, \epsilon_k}$ deleted for all $k \geq 2$ and $\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k \in \{0,1\}$, where the ``strip'' $I_{k, \epsilon_2, \dots, \epsilon_k}$ consists of all pairs $(t,x)$ with $0 < t < 1/3$ and $x$ obeying the estimate
$$ \left| x - f_{k,\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k}(t) \right| < \delta_k$$
where
$$ f_{k,\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k}(t) := \sum_{j=2}^{k-1} \epsilon_j \frac{1-t}{2} \dots \frac{1-t^{j-1}}{2} \frac{1+t^j}{2} + \frac{1-t}{2} \dots \frac{1-t^{k-1}}{2} \frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$ \delta_k := \frac{1-t}{2} \dots \frac{1-t^{k-1}}{2} \frac{t^k}{2}.$$
The width parameter $\delta_k$ is quite small, but fortunately our estimates will be uniform in this parameter and so it will not be necessary to control it.

One can think of this strip $I_{k,\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k}$ as a constant-width interval $[f_{k,\epsilon_2, \dots,\epsilon_k}(t) - \delta_k, f_{k,\epsilon_2, \dots,\epsilon_k}(t) + \delta_k]$ moving in time.  Crucially, this interval moves leftwards at roughly constant speed (so that the strip is oriented "diagonally"):

**Lemma** For any $k \geq 2$ and $\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k \in \{0,1\}$, the function $f_{k,\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k}(t)$ is decreasing for $0 < t < 1/3$ with $-f_{k,\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k}'(t) \sim \sum_{j=2}^{k-1} \frac{\epsilon_j}{2^j} + \frac{1}{2^k}$.

**Proof** For $0 < t < 1/3$ and $j \geq 2$, the function $\frac{1-t}{2} \dots \frac{1-t^{j-1}}{2} \frac{1+t^j}{2}$ is comparable to $2^{-j}$, and has a negative log derivative of
$$ \frac{1}{1-t} + \frac{2t}{1-t^2} + \dots + \frac{(j-1)t^{j-2}}{1-t^{j-1}} - \frac{jt^{j-1}}{1+t^j};$$
since $jt^{j-1} < 0.9 (j-1) t^{j-2}$ (say), this quantity can be seen to be comparable to $1$, so this summand in $f_{k,\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k}$ contributes $\sim \epsilon_j 2^{-j}$ to the negative derivative.  Similarly the final term $\frac{1-t}{2} \dots \frac{1-t^{k-1}}{2} \frac{1}{2}$ contributes $\sim 2^{-k}$, and the claim follows. $\Box$

Now we can establish the claim.  Suppose for contradiction that $S_l$ contained $E \times F$ up to null sets.  Then by [Lebesgue's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem) (or the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem)), there is a point $(t_0,x_0)$ in $S_l$ such that $t_0$ is a point of density of $E$ and $x_0$ is a point of density of $F$.  We can take $(t_0,x_0)$ to lie in the interior of $T$, in particular $x_0 > 0$.

Let $k$ be large. Because the intervals in the $k^{th}$ generation of the Smith-Volterra Cantor set have length $\sim 2^{-k}$, there is $\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k \in \{0,1\}$ such that $|x_0-f_{k,\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k}(t)| \sim 2^{-k}$.  Note that for $k$ large enough we have
$$ x_0 \sim f_{k,\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k}(t_0) \sim \sum_{j=2}^{k-1} \frac{\epsilon_j}{2^j} + \frac{1}{2^k}$$
and so for $k$ large enough we see from the lemma that
$$ -f_{k,\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k}'(t) \sim x_0$$
for all $0 < t < 1/3$.

Now we advance the time variable $t$ from $t_0$ to $t_0 + \frac{1}{2^k x_0}$, so that the interval $[f_{k,\epsilon_2, \dots,\epsilon_k}(t_0) - \delta_k, f_{k,\epsilon_2, \dots,\epsilon_k}(t_0) + \delta_k]$ moves left at roughly constant speed $\sim x_0$, and hence travels a distance $\sim 2^{-k}$.  Because of this, we see that for $C$ a sufficiently large absolute constant, the localized strip
$$ I_{k,\epsilon_2,\dots,\epsilon_k} \cap ([t_0,t_0+\frac{1}{2^k x_0}] \times [x_0-C2^{-k}, x_0+C2^{-k}])$$
contains rectangles $I_j \times J_j$ for $j=1,\dots,J \sim 2^k \delta_k$, with the $I_j$ intervals of length $\sim \delta_k/x_0$ boundedly overlapping in $[t_0,t_0+\frac{1}{2^k x_0}]$ and the $J_j$ intervals of length $\sim \delta_k$ boundedly overlapping in $[x_0-C2^{-k}, x_0+C2^{-k}]$.  For each such rectangle, either $E$ avoids $I_j$ up to null sets, or $F$ avoids $J_j$.  From this and the pigeonhole principle, we see that either the density of $E$ in $[t_0,t_0+\frac{1}{2^k x_0}]$ is less than $1-c$ for some absolute constant $c>0$, or the density of $F$ in $[x_0-C2^{-k}, x_0+C2^{-k}]$ is less than $1-c$.  But, sending $k \to \infty$, this contradicts the fact that $t_0, x_0$ are points of density for $E, F$ respectively.

Comment: Is it very important for the proof that the functions $f_{k,\varepsilon_2,\dots,\varepsilon_k}$ are decreasing? It seems like this could be deduced from a general result like "If $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of non constant polynomials $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $(f_n(t))_n$ is dense in [0,1] for all $t$, then there is no positive measure rectangle disjoint with the graphs of all the $f_n$", if that is true. (In this problem the dense sets would come from, instead of just the center of each removed interval, considering a dense subset of it by linearly interpolating the extremes)

Comment: @SaúlRM This was my initial approach actually, but I was not able to make it work: if the $f_n$ behaved like a "zigzag" function in that their graph resembled a union of horiziontal and vertical line segments, then one could easily construct quite large product sets that avoided the graph of any single $f_n$, and perhaps even all of them at once if the deviation from the horizontal and vertical line segments were small enough.  This zigzag behavior did not seem easy to rule out just from the polynomial nature of the $f_n$ (cf. Weierstrass approximation), so I needed the lemma instead.

Comment: This is a really nice proof! Just one question about the last paragraph - by boundedly overlapping, do you mean something like: there exists some absolute $C_0 > 0$ independent of $k$ such that for all $m \in \{1, \dots, J_k\}$, we have $ | I_m \cap (\cup_{n \neq m} I_n)| < (1 - C_0) |I_m|$? And the same holds for the intervals $J_j$, which allows us to apply the pidgeonhole principle to conclude that, either the volume of $E^c$ in $[t_0, t_0 + \frac{1}{2^k x_0}]$ is bigger than $\frac{1}{2} C_0 \sum_{1 \leq j \leq J_k} |I_j| \sim \frac{1}{2^k}$ or similarly for $F^c$.

Comment: (continued) …and this is enough to conclude the theorem.

Comment: A family of sets is said to be boundedly overlapping if every point is contained in at most a bounded number of sets in the family.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Thank you for the quick clarification!